# When is data slicing (and training separate models) worthwhile?

Tags: random-forest

This question is more general about when one decides to train models on separate slices of a data set, rather than just one model on the entire training set altogether.

So I'm working on a supervised learning problem, where my given model of choice is a RandomForestClassfier (sklearn package). I've fit a model on the entire training set using all the features, that then give predictions on the entire test set.

Then I tried slicing the data sets on a feature that is highly correlated with missing values in other features, trying to avoid the need to deal with missing values. Then for each slice I fit and evaluated separate models and used them on the corresponding slice of the test set.

However in the end, both strategies almost resulted in the same score on the test set. Any pointers on when such data slicing is worthwhile?